# prepareForSegue for TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to pass data from my ViewController to TabBarController by using Objective-C. I'm trying to assign some data to "bottomTabEventList" (which is a property of my custom TabBarController class). Unfortunately, my program crashes by giving unrecognized selector instance error/warning.

In custom header of TabBarController class, named BottomTabview:

```
@interface BottomTabView : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property(strong,nonatomic)EventList *bottomTabEventList;

@end
```

And prepareForSegue method in ViewController.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    BottomTabView *btw = [segue destinationViewController];

    //checking
    if(btw == nil)
        NSLog(@"btw in viewController is nil");
    else
        NSLog(@"btw in viewController is NOT nil");

    if(self.eventList.eventList == nil)
        NSLog(@"eventList in viewController is nil");
    else
        NSLog(@"eventList in viewController is NOT nil"); //end of checking

    btw.bottomTabEventList = self.eventList; //This is where crash appears
}
```

Exact crash log is:

> -[ViewController setBottomTabEventList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe923c6ba00
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController setBottomTabEventList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe923c6ba00'

Segue is from ViewController to BottomTabView and its type is "Present Modally". I'd really appreciate if you can help/guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to cast like this: BottomTabView *btw = (BottomTabView *)[segue destinationViewController];

Comment: That's just casting and helps to silence compiler warnings. It won't magically make btw a BottomTabView class if the destinationViewController isn't one to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that  `btw` is not actually of type `BottomTabView` and is just a `UIViewController` hence the crash log giving:

> [ViewController setBottomTabEventList:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

As `UIViewController` does't know what `BottomTabEventList` is.

You need to make sure that `btw` is actually a `BottomTabView` instance.

Do a little introspection and I bet it will not go into this statement:

```
  if ([btw isKindOfClass:[BottomTabView class]]){
 btw.bottomTabEventList = self.eventList; 
}
```